# Границы элемента panel

Tags: c#

На форме есть элемент `panel`, в котором я двигаю картинку (`picturebox`):

```
//перемещаемся в право
  pictureBox1.Left += 50;
//перемещаемся в низ
  pictureBox1.Top += 50;
```

Т.е. перемещается во все стороны на 50. Подскажите, как сделать, чтобы картинка не выходила за границы элемента `panel`?

Answer (score 3):

Замечательный ведь [сайт](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.panel.aspx).

```
if (pictureBox1.Right >= panel1.ClientSize.Width)
{ /* перешли за правую границу */ }

if (pictureBox1.Bottom >= panel1.ClientSize.Height)
{ /* перешли за нижнюю границу */ }

if (pictureBox1.Left <= 0)
{ /* перешли за левую границу */ }

if (pictureBox1.Top <= 0)
{ /* перешли за верхнюю границу */ }
```